# selector for a href with specific url

Tags: puppeteer, codeceptjs

How would you select an a href element with specific url?

This is my element:

```
<a href="/test/issues/new" class="btn btn-primary float-right" role="button" data-hotkey="c" data-skip-pjax="">
  New issue
</a>
```

I tried `I.click('New issue')` and `I.click("div[href$='/test/issues/new']")` but it fails with `Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement`

Comment: Are you sure it's even on the page? Have you tried taking a screenshot or console-logging the number of this elements?

Answer (score 0):

You try to click div element, `"div[href$='/test/issues/new']"`, but in issue speak about `a` element.

Change it on `"a[href$='/test/issues/new']"`